# H1 tag floating and SEO issues

Tags: html, css, seo, css-float

Couple of questions on H1 tag.

1. Does H1 tag support floating across browsers? Or any other way to achieve floating?
2. Does H1 tag SEO will affect, if i add any HTML inside H1 tag rather than Title of the page or module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Floating works consistent across all (modern (and even IE6 most of the time)) browsers regardless of the element (all elements can be styled equally with CSS (except for form inputs and video/embed elements and the like)
2. This one I'm not sure about but I sometimes put images (a logo perhaps) inside an H1 and at least with Firefox's Web Developer Toolbar's "View document outline"-function it shows the alt-attribute of the img as the H1